How to find and count the number of icons associated with an exe file using powershell?
I would like to get the number of embedded (or associated) icons for an EXE or DLL file.  In a different question, there were some code provided to extract all the icon files, but there was no information showing how to actually use the iconIndex with -1 that should give the total number of icon objects.
From the ExtractIconExW documentation:
UINT ExtractIconExW(
  [in]  LPCWSTR lpszFile,
  [in]  int     nIconIndex,
  [out] HICON   *phiconLarge,
  [out] HICON   *phiconSmall,
        UINT    nIcons
);

with the following explanation for nIconIndex:

If this value is –1 and phiconLarge and phiconSmall are both NULL, the function returns the total number of icons in the specified file. If the file is an executable file or DLL, the return value is the number of RT_GROUP_ICON resources. If the file is an .ico file, the return value is 1.

So I tried to do exactly this with the following:
function get-icon-count {
    Param ( 
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  [string] $SourceFile = 'C:/Windows/system32/shell32.dll',
        [parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [Int32]  $IconIndex  = 0    # -1: To count icons, 
    )

    $code = @'
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Management.Automation;

    namespace System {
        public class FileIconInfo {
            [DllImport("Shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtractIconExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern int ExtractIconExW( string szFileName, int nIconIndex, out IntPtr phiconLarge, out IntPtr phiconSmall, uint nIcons);
        }
    }
'@

#@'
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    $refAssemblies = @([Drawing.Icon].Assembly.Location)    # C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\System.Drawing.Common.dll

    try {
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -PassThru -ReferencedAssemblies $refAssemblies #| Import-Module -Assembly { $_.Assembly }
        $img = [System.FileIconInfo]::ExtractIconExW($SourceFile, -1, $null, $null, 1)    
    } Catch {
        Write-Host -f Red "[ERROR] Failed in ExtractIconExW()!"
        Write-Host -f Red "[ERROR] $_"
        $_ | select *
        Return
    }

    Write-Host -f DarkYellow "The number of icon indexes fund are: $([int32]$img)"
    Return $([int32]$img)
}


However, running this with:
. .\extract-icon.ps1 && get-icon-count 'C:\<path-to>\shell32.dll'
You can try with any EXE's or DLL's that are known to contain a lot of icons. Like these:
'C:\Windows\SystemResources\shell32.dll.mun'
'C:\Windows\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun'  

But I get the Exception:
Argument: '3' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
It seem that it doesn't like the $null.
How can I fix the script to get the number of icons in a DLL/EXE?

If you're just looking to get icon count probably ExtractIcon is simpler than ExtractIconEx (which is meant to extract large and small icons). In your current implementation you're also missing a call to DestroyIcon to dispose the handle as suggested in Remarks. (EDIT: This is not needed when getting the icon count - -1 as argument to nIconIndex - my bad).
Add-Type -Namespace Native -Name ShellApi '
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr ExtractIconW(
    [In] IntPtr hInst,
    [In] string lpszExeFileName,
    int nIconIndex);

public static int GetIconCount(string path)
{
    return ExtractIconW(IntPtr.Zero, path, -1).ToInt32();
}'

Usage is just by passing the assembly name or path to executable or .ico:
[Native.ShellApi]::GetIconCount('shell32.dll')               # 329
[Native.ShellApi]::GetIconCount('user32.dll')                # 7
[Native.ShellApi]::GetIconCount((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path) # 1


Fabulous! It seem as a rookie on Win API, I keep over-engineer my code. Perhaps due to somewhat unclear MS documentation. On one page they say use this, then they say to use that, etc. Love the simplicity you provided here, TY.

@not2qubit glad it helped and yes, p/invoke is not an easy topic especially if you don't have a good base on c# and .net

when using -Name ClassName the using statements aren't needed unless it doesn't compile at which point those statements are passed thru via -UsingNamespace @not2qubit

I found the solution over here.
With some minor adjustments, it now works as expected with:
function get-icon-count {
    Param ( 
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  [string] $SourceFile = 'C:/Windows/system32/shell32.dll'   #"$env:SystemRoot\system32\shell32.dll"
    )
    
    # public static extern int ExtractIconExW( string lpszFile, int nIconIndex, out IntPtr phiconLarge, out IntPtr phiconSmall, int nIcons);
    $code = @'
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace System {
        public class FileIconInfo {
            [DllImport("Shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtractIconExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern int ExtractIconEx( string lpszFile, int nIconIndex, out IntPtr phiconLarge, out IntPtr phiconSmall, int nIcons);
        }
    }
'@

    [System.IntPtr] $phiconSmall = 0
    [System.IntPtr] $phiconLarge = 0

    Write-Host -f Gray "`n[INFO] Getting the total number of icons in file: $SourceFile"
    If  (-not (Test-path -Path $SourceFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) ) {
        Write-Host -f Red "[ERROR] Source file does not exist!"
    }

    try {
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code 
        $nImages = [System.FileIconInfo]::ExtractIconEx($SourceFile, -1, [ref] $phiconLarge, [ref] $phiconSmall, 0)
    } Catch {
        Write-Host -f Red "[ERROR] Failed to ExtractIconExW() from file!"
        Write-Host -f Red "[ERROR] $_"
        Return
    }

    Write-Host -f DarkYellow "[INFO] The number of icon indexes fund are: $([int32]$nImages)"
}

# . .\extract-icon.ps1 && get-icon-count 'C:\<path-to>\imageres.dll.mun'

# Output:
# [INFO] Getting the total number of icons in file: C:\<path-to>\imageres.dll.mun
# [INFO] The number of icon indexes fund are: 360

Great!

For .ICO files you can read bytes 4 and 5 as Int16 to get the number of icons in the file:
Read the header: $bytes = Get-Content -Path $SourceFile -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 6
Next, convert bytes 4 and 5 to Int16: [BitConverter]::ToInt16($bytes, 4)

Cool. Thank you. I will add that functionality (elsewhere), as I also noticed it doesn't catch the icons for all file types.

@Theo Any suggestions where (in windows) to find an ICO file that have many icons inside?

I believe all Windows icons are compiled in icon sets (.dll) but there are lots of icons to be found on the internet
